# How does rake db::migrate actually work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've just really started with Ruby and Rails, and one of the things that I find myself really enjoying is the conventions it makes you use.

I want to mimic that behavior in my own non-Ruby projects.

My question is how does it actually work? I know I can look through the Rails code, but I'm not that far enough in my understanding to know what's going on in it.

I know that it takes a baseline script and then runs update schema changes against it. But how does it know what version it's on? How would I mimic that in another framework / database?

Comment: It looks to see what the last migration was. It runs the ones that come after that. *Very* broadly, it's a DSL for writing SQL (reversible SQL in 3.1). Can you be more specific?

Comment: It works in a lot of ways... What specific aspect of it eludes you?

Comment: Updated the question. I'm speaking specifically about migrate and teardown (i.e. rake migrate rollback).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Note: This is true so far as Rails 2.x.  It may not hold true for rails 3, as I haven't spent as much time with Rails 3 as I would have liked.*

Rails creates a special hidden table named `schema_migrations`.  This table has a single column named `version`.  And there is a row in this column for every migration you have.  The value being the timestamp that matches the migrations filename timestamp.

When you migrate, it looks through all your migrations in chronological order (also happens to be alphabetical order due to the timstamp based naming convention).  For every migration it looks for a matching row in the `schema_migrations` table.  If it fails to find one, then it runs that migration, and adds the timestamp the table.  If it does find one, it assumes it already ran and simply skips it.

The result is that 2 developers can both commit migrations in any order, and it's fine.  This is because Rails knows exactly what migrations have been run and which haven't, regardless of when your database first saw them.

So to do something yourself like this, you simply need a way to permanently store this state about which steps been taken and which have not.

Comment: What's the relevance of schema.rb in this context? I match all migrations with the database column, I would have no use for the schema.rb?

Comment: It's like a photoshop file. The migrations are the layers and schema.rb is the final flattened result of all the layers combined. So if you need to just load up the schema into your test database you can do that quickly instead of running hundreds of migrations sequentially to get the same result.

Comment: I understand the concept, and also the photoshop analogy :) But I wasnt sure about the use case, but what you said makes a lot of sense: to load schema for test database. I wonder if there is other use cases?

Comment: I also use it as a reference for what columns exist for a model when I forget.  "Does a user have a full_name, or first_name and a last_name?"