# Why is Rails running a migration that is prior to the schema version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I have a migration with version number 20120926232105. My schema is at version 20121003190827.

My site is hosted on Heroku, and when I run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate -a my-app
```

I get an error that the table it is trying to create in migration 20120926232105 already exists (as it should). I don't get it - isn't the whole point of the schema_migration table to record which was the last successful migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235899/how-does-rake-migrate-actually-work) explains it pretty well.

Basically, there's a table somewhere called "schema_migrations". Your migration's "version number" is actually just a time stamp. Further, there's no record of a migration with that timestamp in your 'schema_migrations' table. Since the migration exists, and its timestamp wasn't found in the 'schema_migrations' table, Rake knows to run it.

Try `grep -r "table_name" db/migrate` and see if it's in there twice.

Comment: Exactly. Schemas used to be described by a single number, but that doesn't play very nicely with branching and merging or distributed development in general. So now, your schema version isn't the number of the most recent migration, it's the *set* of migrations that have been run.